# How to create paypal transaction server side with older "Buy Now" / form style buttons?

Tags: paypal

I have to set up an older "Buy Now" html form style button to work with an IPN system (ie. not smart buttons / REST api). I'd like to have the buttons call a server script which handles setting up the transaction and passing the form data if possible to avoid the possibility of the user messing with the values. I'm not sure if this is actually possible though or how it would work if it is possible.

I could obviously post my own form data to Paypal from my server but I don't know how I could then handle redirecting the user to paypal.

Is this possible? Or is validating the transactions after they've been completed the only way?

Answer (score 0):

> I could obviously post my own form data to PayPal from my server but I don't know how I could then handle redirecting the user to PayPal.

The v2/checkout/orders REST API ("Create Order" and "Capture Order", [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls)) exist exactly for this purpose, with or without Smart Buttons for the user's approval flow.

Smart Buttons are to *avoid* a redirect for approval, which is highly desirable. But as your requirements are to not use them for some reason (??), you would instead create an order and redirect to the given `approval_url`, and the user will return to the `redirect_url` you specify in your create order request, and you can then show a review page and capture the order.

Comment: It's less about avoiding the rest api and buttons in particular as it is I have to use IPN instead of the webhooks and afaik, the rest API only supports webhooks. If everything you said is still compatible with IPN then that would be ideal i guess.

Comment: An IPN listener set at the account level is supported for Smart Payment Button + REST API transactions.  The v2/checkout/orders API doesn't support overriding it with a 'notify_url' parameter, as previous APIs did, mainly because IPN is a very old and clunky service and it's strange to be combining it with the newest API and payment buttons. But it will work as a notification for all payments received to the PayPal account, that is the literal purpose of the old IPN service (instant payment notification)

Comment: Hmmm. I have been working under the assumption that I didn't have access to the account level IPN url. I guess I'll go ask if there's any reason I can't just make a separate paypal account so that I can do this.

Comment: Creating a whole separate account for the purpose of being able to use IPN? Woah. That's, erm, stunning considering how much better it would be to find a way to avoid depending on an old service like IPN altogether...